# Two lists - get common fields?

Tags: c#, linq

I have two `List<object>`. A field in the objects is party_id.

Is there a way, using LINQ, to get a list back of only the common party_ids? So, maybe join the lists on Party ID and then return the ones with matches?

In SQL, I guess I'd do:

```
SELECT DISTINCT party_id FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 on table1.party_id = table2.party_id
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without pulling out Reflector and verifying the implementations of the aforementioned workable solutions, I think it would be most efficient to use `Join(...)`:

```
var party_on_dude = from table1
                    join table2 on table1.party_id equals table2.party_id
                    select table1.party_id;
```

Comment: It seems to me that without doing due diligence, it's not terribly helpful to offer micro optimizations whose efficacy you haven't even investigated or explained.

Comment: @Kirk, your criticism is fair.  However, it is hardly a micro-optimization unless you know __a priori__ that the lists are small.  Moreover, you may not even be aware as to whether the lists are in memory or in a database, in which case the structure of the query certainly comes into play.

Comment: Frankly I was giving you the benefit of the doubt. :)  Without an *explanation*, I'm not convinced it's even an optimization at all.

Comment: @Rohan, what are you talking about?  In what sense is this "best practice" when contrasted with dasblinkenlight's answer?  What evidence do you have that this solution performs better **at all**?  (And at least as importantly, dasblinkenlight's answer is **far** more clear and concise, which should count for something too.)

Comment: @Kirk, the first `Select` will iterate over each member of `table1`.  The second, inner `Select` will iterate over each member of `table2`.  The `Intersect` will iterate over the results of the first `Select` for each member of the result of the second `Select`: T1 + T2 + s(T1)*s(T2)... and if it goes the database (which is unknown for reusable code) that would be one hell of a query instead of a simple `inner join`.

Comment: Of course, someone did say that ["premature optimization is the root of all evil"](http://blog.expensify.com/2011/08/26/ceo-friday-premature-optimization-is-the-root-of-all-evil/).

Comment: @jonnyGold Any database worth its salt, as well as most toy databases not worthy of a second look, would implement `intersect` as `O(M+N)` with a hash table. Same goes for the in-memory `Intersect`: it should be `O(M+N)`, not `O(M*N)`.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, agreed.  Sadly, Linq to SQL won't emit it as `SELECT party_id FROM table1 INTERSECT SELECT party_id FROM table2`.  The expression tree will emit something much, much more... interesting.  The visitor simply isn't that smart.  It will do what it is told.  Plus, if this is in-memory with Linq to Objects, the same thing applies.

Comment: @jonnyGold "if this is in-memory with Linq to Objects, the same thing applies." That's not what is going on: you can download the source of .NET and check for yourself. Line 756 of `Enumerable.cs` implements `Intersect` by calling `IntersectIterator`; line 765 implements `IntersectIterator` by creating a set of items from `second`, and then iterating `first` to `yield return` a set of distinct items.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight "implements IntersectIterator by creating a set of items from second, and then iterating first".  Can you explain how that is not `second` * `first` equality comparisons?

Comment: @jonnyGold "Can you explain how that is not second * first equality comparisons?" Hash set insertions and lookups are both `O(1)` operations, so the total is `O(second + first)`.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight - the use of a `HashSet` would explain it.

Answer (score 4):

You can try this:

```
table1.Select(r => r.party_id).Intersect(table2.Select(r => r.party_id))
```

Answer (score 3):

How about

```
var results = list1.Where(f => list2.Exists(s => f.party_id == s.party_id))
                   .Select(x => x.party_id);
```